# How to remove all child elements of a dom node using typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, dom

I am using angular 4 to create a grid with pagination. I have this looping in place using tabledata.data element. When I call pagination function I am able to get  variable with new tabledata.data and it fills the existing table with new entries. BUT THE PROBLEM is it keeps old entries only there.

```
            <table style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th *ngFor="let head of tableData.gridhead">{{head}}</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let ddata of tableData.data; let i = ddata" (click)="setClickedRow(ddata)" [class.active]="ddata.discountauthorizationid == selectedRow">
                        <td *ngFor="let dr of tableData.record | paginate: { itemsPerPage: pageItem, currentPage: p }">{{ddata[dr]}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Lets say I have this structure

```
---->   th th th th th

row 1   td td td td td
```

after pagination function call
What I am getting :

```
---->   th th th th th

row 1   td td td td td

row 2   td td td td td
```

Expected :

```
---->   th th th th th

row 2   td td td td td
```

How to remove row 1 after pagination function called? Or How to remove all the rows and then add new row 2.

Comment: The issue is very specific to your case and requires http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . There shouldn't be a problem like that because you use ngFor and don't deal with DOM nodes directly.

Comment: `*ngFor` doesn't keep old entries. The array you pass to `*ngFor` does. Fix your array and all will be fine.

Comment: Hello Gunter,  I have checked array. Its giving correct value. Still I am not able to solve it. Even if ngfor loop is not there,  the issue persist like buttons and whole component is getting appended. I'm stuck with this issue from last many days. Not able to find a single solution to this.  Can you please help me?